# blurry image in canvas when using fabricjs 1.5.0

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, fabricjs

this is how my code looks like when using fabricjs in a cordova app

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    capturePhoto();
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerWidth });
    canvas.renderAll();
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {canvas.setBackgroundImage('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+imageData,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),{
originX: 'left',
originY: 'top'
  });
  }

 function capturePhoto() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
    allowEdit : true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true, 
    correctOrientation: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
    cameraDirection: 0});

}

<canvas id="canvas" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"></canvas>
```

However, after capturing the photo, the photo ends up being blurry on the canvas window. Does anyone have a clue as to why this happens?

P.S. when using fabricjs 1.6.0rc, the image no longer appears blurry, but 1.5.0 has functionality which I require

Comment: which function do you have on 1.5.0 that is missing on 1.6.0?

Comment: 1.5.0 is able to build for touch events while 1.6.0 is not

Answer (score 3):

to avoid blurriness on images of fabric 1.5.0 override the standard strokeWidth value of the image object:

```
fabric.Image.prototype.strokeWidth = 0;
```

And you should be ok.

Add this line of code anywhere in your script after loading the library and before loading the images.

If working on mobile phones with devicePixelRation different from 1, try to see if

```
canvas.enableRetinaScaling = true; // OR false
```

makes any difference.

Comment: sorry but where should this be added? I don't think that this fixes the issue as manually changing the default value of strokewidth within fabricjs does not solve the issue either

Comment: this has been the major cause of blurriness after 1.5.0 release. If it does not fix, please provide a fiddle to test the image. The problem could be in the image itself.

Comment: I understand that there have been apparently multiple causes of image bluriness e.g. strokewidth and canvas.imagesmoothingenabled, is there anything else which has been related to image from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0? the problem is certainly not in the image as it is fine on 1.6.0

Comment: if you can provide a fiddle i will help, otherways i cannot do anything.

Comment: it seems that I am unable to reproduce this error on jsfiddle even when using practically the same code as my cordova app. could this have something to do with the display of my mobile device?

Comment: check your "window.devicePixelRatio" and see if is not integer. this could cause blurriness. Updated answer.

Comment: nevermind, issue resolved by building touch and gestures into a v1.6.0 manually

Comment: blurriness from image can derive from: retinaScaling, strokeWidth odd number, imageSmoothingEnabled. For every of those 3 there are fixes between 1.5.0 and 1.6.0, bau all the fixes are the one described in the answer.